# How to TRANSLATE unicode to latin in Teradata?

Tags: unicode, teradata, latin

My table contains a field `lastName` that is `UNICODE`

I need to implement the `SOUNDEX` function, but it won't work because it requires only `latin`. So I tried converting it to `latin` but still get the same error `only latin letters allowed`

Here is what i tried

```
SEL * 
FROM tab_test
WHERE SOUNDEX(REGEXP_REPLACE(lastName, '[^A-Z]', '')) = 'smith' 



SEL * 
FROM tab_test
WHERE SOUNDEX(TRANSLATE(lastNameUSING unicode_to_latin)) = 'smith'
```

How can I correct the issue

---

**EDIT**

Here is what i tried as dnoeth suggests. But it still does not work

```
     SEL * 
     FROM tab_test
     WHERE SOUNDEX(TRANSLATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(
     lastName,'[^a-zA-Z]','') USING   
     UNICODE_TO_LATIN))  = 's530'
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Here is the query that does not work

```
 SEL  lastName, REGEXP_REPLACE(lastName, '[^a-zA-Z]', '') lastName_regex 
 FROM (SEL * 
 FROM tab_test
 WHERE personId < 10 
 ) der 
 WHERE SOUNDEX(REGEXP_REPLACE(lastName, '[^a-zA-Z]', '')) = 's530'
```

---

The result of the REGEXP sub query is the following

```
SEL  lastName, REGEXP_REPLACE(lastName, '[^a-zA-Z]', '') lastName_regex 
 FROM (SEL * 
 FROM tab_test
 WHERE personId < 10 
 ) der
```

Result  is copied directly from teradata sql assistant

```
    LASTNAME    lastName_regex
1   Smith                   Smith              
2   Smith                   Smith              
3   Smith                   Smith              
4   Smith                   Smith              
5   Smith                   Smith              
6   Smith                   Smith              
7   Smith                   Smith              
8   Smith                   Smith
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex removes lowercase a to z, too.

So try either

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(lastName, '[^a-zA-Z]', '') -- explicitly add lowercase
```

or

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(lastName, '[^A-Z]', '',1,0,'i')) -- do a case insensitive comparison
```

Btw, the result of a `SOUNDEX('smith')` is not 'smith', but 's530'.

Comment: I still get the same error. THe regex does not help

Comment: This should work, strange. What's your exact Teradata release (`select * from dbc.dbcinfoV where InfoKey = 'Release'`)? Can you show some of the bad data, just the result of REGEXP_REPLACE?

Comment: The release is  `14.00.07.14` The bad data looks normal. I copied it directly from the SQL assistant. This small sample above does not work

Comment: There must be something else, the data you showed can't result in an error when using SOUNDEX.

Answer (score 0):

You might need

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

i.e, the "+"

Answer (score 0):

Try USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN WITH ERROR